# Is it possible to distinguish cookies with the same name by domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

- User gets cookie named `X` from site `a.com`.
- User gets cookie named `X` from `sub.a.com` (a subdomain of `a.com`).
- Both of the cookies `X` use their respective domains.

Given the assumptions above, can JavaScript identify one cookie `X` out of the two by using domain info, then update it?

Comment: No. A page in the subdomain only gets the subdomain cookie, all other pages in the domain get the top-level cookie.

Comment: JS and the server only get one cookie with any particular name. They get the most specific one for their domain.